# Format String - number

Tags: python, string, format

This is a easy question but i need explanation.
In this code Why the output is 100:

```
x = 100.1205
y = str(x)[6]
print("{:.{}f}".format(x,y))
```

Comment: The output is `{:.{}f}.format(x,y)`.

Comment: The output is not 100; it is the literal string `"{:.{}f}.format(x,y)"`.

Comment: Its obviously a typo, its supposed to be `print("{:.{}f}".format(x,y))`, which does print 100

Comment: thanks, how it formats the string, step i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 100.1205
y = str(x)[6]  ## This is turning x into a string and grabbing the 6th character which is 0
print("{:.{}f}".format(x,y)) # this is saying print x to the decimal place 
#specified by the value of y (zeroth digit) which is 100
```

Comment: which means deletes decimal points?

Comment: you can think of it like that. if you were to put print("{:.{}f}".format(x,2)) it would print out 100.12

Comment: `x.yf` means print `x` digits before the `.` and `y` digits after the decimal point.